# Conditional required typescript

Tags: typescript, types

So i have a function that have two parameters

the first param is to choose the variant name and it's required,
the second param is for preferences, if the preferences has undefined type what I want is it should be filled with first param only, no need to type undefined in the second param

[image]

This is my code

```
type VariantTypes = {
  Apple: {
    amount: number
  },
  Air: undefined
}

function Spawn<variant extends keyof VariantTypes>(variant: variant, prefs: VariantTypes[variant]) {

}

Spawn('Apple', {
  amount: 7
})

Spawn('Air') // Second parameter has undefined type, it should not warn me an error if I fill only the first params
Spawn('Air', undefined) // I have to do this, but this is not what I want when second param has undefined type
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible in current version of TypeScript. Even boiling this down to a ternary op choosing between regular type and undefined/void (essentially hardcoding what you did) doesn't give any meaningful results.

Comment: @raina77ow i think it's possible, react-navigation has this pattern when navigating to another screen, for example when navigating to screen A you are not required to give any params, when navigating to screen B you are required to give some params etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @aleksxor, from your answer I have the clue how to do it, this is what I got working for me

```
type VariantTypes = {
  Apple: {
    amount: number
  },
  Cherry: {
    color: 'red' | 'blue'
  },
  Air: undefined
}

function Spawn<variant extends keyof VariantTypes>(...args: undefined extends VariantTypes[variant] ? [variant] : [variant, VariantTypes[variant]]) {
  
}

Spawn('Apple', {
  amount: 7
})
Spawn('Cherry', {
  color: 'blue'
})
Spawn('Air')
Spawn('Air', undefined) // it will shows error
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgJwJZwHbACrggZygXigG8AoKKAQTDABsIAuYs8qOAWwHsBXdR1LtgCMICZgF8ANMwDCACxEIQjUiygBjDjQ4JGAcgQQAJrqgAfKLsE0uEXeKnkKSHVB6GIAMySojJMSRIPHjVgJA5UKABlMDgAd1QAHgA3RBR0KAgAD2AIVEM8AGsIEA4PWFS0TGwcAD4ACgA6JsQAcxxGN09vIwzs3Pzy5EqsSBwAbRSh9ABdKAB%20KAmKmahGJangCUG0qtH1nenpgEomcj8A6LjUOt0qWlstlVZOHmBGAHY-I5JL%20Ju5BQgXSPZgaLQuSzWWxfH4xP63Zy6b6-a4IhDA1x5Lo%20QxHIA)

Answer (score 2):

You may use [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) and [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to create a simple helper type:

```ts
type Args<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = K extends unknown 
    ? T[K] extends undefined 
        ? [K] 
        : [K, T[K]] 
    : never
type VariantTypesArgs = Args<VariantTypes> // ["Apple", { amount: number }] | ["Air"]
```

Then you just have to type your function arguments with this type:

```ts
declare function Spawn(...args: [...Args<VariantTypes>]): void
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mZ8oDw)

Comment: It works but, for example if I have Cherry: {
    color: 'red' | 'blue'
 }

when I Spawn('Apple', {}) it will give me autocomplete option color too, the unnecessary autocomplete option should not show :(